# Is there a way to escape `]` PHP <input name="array[with-text-keys]"> notation?

Tags: php

I am maintaining a legacy PHP application which uses many string indexed arrays as ipnut names. There are many snippets similar to this:

```
<input name="<?= 
    htmlspecialchars(
        'array_name[' . $string_index . ']',
        ENT_QUOTES
    ); ?>" 
/>
```

This worked pretty well for a few years until someone used `a_string_with[square_brackets]` as `$string_index`.

This value broken the app as it was send to the server as:

```
array_name[a_string_with[square_brackets]]=value
```

...which was interpreted by PHP as `var_dump($_POST)`:

```
array (size=1)
  'array_name' => 
    array (size=1)
      'a_string_with[square_brackets' => string 'any_value' (length=9)
```

Notice the missing closing square bracket `]` in the array key. It seems that second square bracket (and everything that follows it) is silently ignored by php.

I have searched for a while, and could not find a way to escape the closing bracket that would be automaticly interpreted by php when parsing request.

I have decided to replace this keys with base64 encoded values, but I wonder if PHP really does not have such feature?

**Minimal example**
Just create a file contining one php line:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
```

... and call it:

```
http://localhost/var_dump.php?array_name[a_string_with[square_brackets]]=any_value
```

Comment: Thtat looks like a strange requirement - why not use proper arrays for this?

Comment: I am wondering what the `rawurlencode` is doing in there? With that, you should not have gotten an array under `$_POST['array_name']` to begin with, but this should have created a "flat" array in $_POST, with the key `array_name%5Bfoobar5D` for that particular input field ...? And that should work the same way, no matter how many "levels" of nested square brackets are in there.

Comment: It seems there really isn’t: <https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/b27d2fffbc551cebc3696718028bd22ebbc93dde/main/php_variables.c#L176-L199>.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]. There's too much vague info that makes it hard to really understand what is going on. Include the output or error message as well, please. In any case, you can always write PHP code to generate whatever HTML you want, even if it's not as trivially easy as you'd like it to be.

Comment: @NicoHaase: After 15 years of bloatware there is noone to ask "Why"

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt This is pretty minimal. How could you make this more minimal?

Comment: @CBroe: That is right, I was typing the code directly in SO and not tested it. Actual code does not have rawurlencode, but is to bloated to paste in question. I will edit my question.

Comment: It's not just about minimal, but also about reproducible. I can't put that code into a file to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Are you sure? I was able to reproduce this after removing `rawurlencode()`

Comment: The `$string_index` portion is what _should_ get URL encoding applied to it here - then you end up with a field name `array_name[a_string_with%5Bsquare_brackets%5D]`, and that would create `$_POST['array_name']['a_string_with%5Bsquare_brackets%5D']`. PHP doesn't URL-decode the actual keys for you here, so if you need the key to be plain `a_string_with[square_brackets]` on that second level, you would have to take care of decoding _that_ yourself again.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I have added the simplest example possible

Comment: @CBroe: I went with base64 encoded key, cause it is used in other places of this applicaiton, but it seems that it is the only possibility to encode and decode array keys manually.

Comment: @Dharman: How? In the first snippet, there's obviously `$string_index` missing. Also, the code that "worked pretty well", in what way did it break? Like, expected and actual outcome? Forcing the author to focus on the core of the problem is one reason that [mcve] is required. The questions simply get better in quality.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The line below the example says exactly what the contents of `$string_index` is. It broke in a way that the `]` got stripped. This is a really well written question and I don't understand why you are asking for more clarity. Here's an executable example of exactly the same problem: https://3v4l.org/ujuh8

Comment: You can obviously get the unparsed query string from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. However `parse_str()` mangles it just the same, so if you want to keep the square brackets in the URL, you can always parse the raw query string yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to escape this behaviour in any way. At the end of the day it is a bug in PHP, one that is difficult to eradicate since the removal of register_globals.

You can work around this in a few ways. One would be to use `rawurlencode()` on the `$string_index` and then when you receive that value in PHP you can use `rawurldecode()`

Another option would be to do what PHP does and replace "invalid" characters with `_`. Something like:

```
$string_index = str_replace(['[', ']', '.', ' '], '_', $string_index);
```

None of the above solutions are great and what's worse there are valid examples of forms in HTML that can't use such workarounds. So yeah... PHP is broken and until someone writes an RFC to fix this in PHP, we will continue to have such problems.